# Why background image for body is not going to bottom in this jsfiddle example

Tags: html, css

See this jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/z7JBr/4/

this is css

```
body {background:url(http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/files/2007/06/iphone_34.jpg) no-repeat center bottom red}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give your body some height, since it doesn't have enough content to make it all the way to the bottom.

```
body {
    background:url(http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/files/2007/06/iphone_34.jpg) no-repeat center bottom red;
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@jitendra; put `body, html{height:100%}` in your `body` because your body have no `height` right now

Comment: but why body taking color but not image at bottom. if body has no height then color of background should be black

Comment: actually the height of the body is zero but check this for more http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html for example remove no-repeat from your background then saw the image takes entire window.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the background image stopping before the bottom of the page. In my CSS I had put `body{background-image:url(http://domain.com/image.jpg);}` and it turned out that in another part of the CSS i had `body{background:#fff;}`. When I took this second part out it worked fine.

I know this is an old post but it comes top of Google search so I thought I'd try and help someone having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that as well as what has been stated about the height you also need to make sure that your child divs, that will effectively be increasing the body's height, are not set to position absolute.  I ran into this where some styles being set for mobil were not set inside a media query and it messed the background image up.